# How can I update value in the array by a condition on the php?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

I have alt array like this :

```
$alt = array('chelsea', 'mu', 'arsenal');
```

I have photoList array like this :

```
$photoList = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 1,
        'name'  => 'chelsea.jpg',
        'alt'   => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 2,
        'name'  => 'mu.jpg',
        'alt'   => ''
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 3,
        'name'  => 'arsenal.jpg',
        'alt'   => ''
    )
);
```

I want to check a condition

If index plus 1 in the alt array same with id in the photoList array, it will update alt in the photoList array with value of alt array by index plus 1

I try like this :

```
foreach($photoList as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($alt as $key2 => $value2) {
        if($value1['id'] == $key2+1)
            $value1['alt'] = $value2;
    }
}
```

Then I check with :

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($photoList);echo '</pre>';
```

The alt is still empty. It does not update

I hope the result like this :

```
photoList = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 1,
        'name'  => 'chelsea.jpg',
        'alt'   => 'chelsea'
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 2,
        'name'  => 'mu.jpg',
        'alt'   => 'mu'
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 3,
        'name'  => 'arsenal.jpg',
        'alt'   => 'arsenal'
    )
);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: you'd have to use the vars ($value1) [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: this should do it: `foreach($photoList as $key1 => &$value1) { ...`

Comment: Why not `alt = explode('.', name)[0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach will be to do that:

```
foreach($photoList as $key => $value)
    $photoList[$key]['alt'] = $alt[$key];
```

This way round you use only one loop. Also, what's wrong with your original loop is that you are assigning the value to the temporary variable inside the loop. This is not affecting the array you are looping over.

**EDIT**:

I just figured out that you do not need to care about `$photoList[$key]['id']` at all. It's irrelevant in this example as the order of the elements is the same in both arrays.

Comment: @man0v Okay thanks. For my case, your answer is more helpful. I will accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the vars ($value1) [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
                           // THIS & is the trick
foreach($photoList as $key1 => &$value1) {
    foreach ($alt as $key2 => $value2) {
        if($value1['id'] == $key2+1)
            $value1['alt'] = $value2;
    }
}
```

Without that you work with an 'internal copy' of the sub-item `$value1`, so `$photoList` doesn't get updated.